# ASP.NET MVC, EF and Ninject : Different ObjectContext issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, ninject

I'm using Ninject for DI and injecting IDbContext to my repositories as constructor parameter. I get a ***"The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects."*** error while trying to do something like this:

This is my controller's **action method**:

```
 public ActionResult BindSpace(int spaceId, int managerId)
    {
        Space space = _spaceService.GetSpace(spaceId);
        Manager manager = _managerService.GetManager(managerId);

        if (space != null && manager != null)
        {
            _spaceService.BindManager(space, manager);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("GetSpaceBindingForm", new { id = space.Id });
    }
```

This is the **service method**:

```
public void BindManager(Space space, Manager manager)
    {
        if (space != null && manager != null)
        {
            space.Managers.Add(manager);
            _spaceRepo.Update(space);
        }
    }
```

There was no problem while adding and updating non-related entities.

There is no problem when I use:

`ninjectKernel.Bind<IDbContext>().To<SPBSObjectContext>().InSingletonScope().WithConstructorArgument("nameOrConnectionString", "ShoppingPointBrowsingSystem");`

I searched the web and everyone implements and uses NinjectModule abstract base class, but I have the following code. What am I doing wrong here?

This is the **injection** part:

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IKernel ninjectKernel;

    public NinjectControllerFactory()
    {
        ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType == null ? null : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    {
        // HTTP Context
        ninjectKernel.Bind<HttpContextBase>().ToMethod(context => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));

        // Context
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IDbContext>().To<SPBSObjectContext>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("nameOrConnectionString", "ShoppingPointBrowsingSystem");

        // Repositories
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IRepository<Admin>>().To<EfRepository<Admin>>().InRequestScope();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IRepository<Manager>>().To<EfRepository<Manager>>().InRequestScope();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IRepository<ShoppingCenterSpace>>().To<EfRepository<ShoppingCenterSpace>>().InRequestScope();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IRepository<IndependentStoreSpace>>().To<EfRepository<IndependentStoreSpace>>().InRequestScope();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IRepository<Space>>().To<EfRepository<Space>>().InRequestScope();

        // Services
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IAuthenticationService<Admin>>().To<AdminFormsAuthenticationService>();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IAdminService>().To<AdminService>();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IManagerService>().To<ManagerService>();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IShoppingCenterSpaceService>().To<ShoppingCenterSpaceService>();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<IIndependentStoreSpaceService>().To<IndependentStoreSpaceService>();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<ISpaceService>().To<SpaceService>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do the two instances come from?

Comment: Where does the `EFRepository` get its `IDbContext` from. Looks to me like each is creating its own.

Comment: They are all getting the IDbContext injected as constructor parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InRequestScope` requires the Ninject.MVC3 extenison instead of an own ControllerFactory . Otherwise it behaves like `InTransientScope`

Comment: Can you provide some implementation details? I searched some articles about MVC3 extension but everyone suggests different ways of doing it including yours.